# __dirname no funciona correctamente en proyecto de QUASAR - VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

gracias por tomarse un momento para leer mi problema.

Estoy realizando un proyecto en QUASAR.dev con VUE CLI y ELECTRON.
mi problema es que cuando uso `__dirname` dentro de `win.loadFile()` la direccion rut que me devuelve no es la carpeta raiz del proyecto sino una que se encuentra dentro de esta.

funcion - script

```
createWin() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow ({
    width:500,
    height:500,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: process.env.QUASAR_NODE_INTEGRATION,
      nodeIntegrationInWorker: process.env.QUASAR_NODE_INTEGRATION,
    }
  })
  win.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, '../pages/Error404.vue'))

  win.once("ready-to-show", function () {
    win.show
  })
}
```

me devuelve "file:///C:/wamp64/www/miapp/.quasar/electron/src/pages/Error404.vue"
cuando debería devolver "file:///C:/wamp64/www/miapp/src/pages/Error404.vue"

miapp es el directorio root de mi proyecto. y me esta agregando siempre ".quasar/electron" no se porqué.

no se porque me esta agregando eso.

dejo imagen de la estructura de carpetas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La parte de solución, se escribe en la parte inferior, donde dice "Tu Respuesta", una vez que edites la pregunta y hayas agregado la respuesta, espero un lapso de 24 horas aproximadamente para marcar la respuesta como aceptada, de tal modo que tu pregunta colabora para la buena salud de SOes (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos :D

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCION

Segun la documentacion de QUASAR para el acceso a archivo desde ELECTRON. __dirname y __filename no funcionan como deberían durante el proceso de desarrollo. para ello proponen usar la siguiente solución.

win.loadFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../pages/Error404.vue'))

Aunque esto me abre una ventana con el código del archivo y no el renderizado. Gracias